# How to add CSV file to dictionary using specific keys in python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've Googled and search this site, but past questions haven't helped me. I want to add a complicated CSV file to a dictionary in python. The file has six columns.

```
0   0   1   A   PAID    Gave money to
0   5   5   A   CRASH   Stock market calamity
0   11  10  A   BARD    Singing poet
```

This is a crossword game. Each column corresponds to a value in the game. Take the second row for example:

```
0==y axis on crossword grid
5== x axis on crossword grid
5== the box number on crossword grid
A== Direction on crossword grid (across)
CRASH== the word to be guessed.
Stock market calamity== the crossword clue.
```

I want to assigned all of these to a dictionary, let's call it wordDict, then place wordDict into "big dictionary", called puzzle, using the the word as the key name.

I did this the manual way. There's no way I can do the whole file like this. It is too tedious. There's 84 lines in the CSV file. I want to use a for loop to get this done, but have no idea as my textbook does not show how this is done.

Keep in mind I read the CSV file in as f one line at a time stripping the tabs out and newline characters

Here's how I did it manually like the textbook:

```
wordDict['y']='0'
wordDict['x']='5'
wordDict['box']='5'
wordDict['direction']='A'
wordDict['word']='CRASH'
wordDict['clue']='Stock market calamity'
puzzle['CRASH']='wordDict'
```

Is there a way to loop through the whole like this?

Comment: *"I've Googled and search this site, but past questions haven't helped me"* - I just can't believe that. There are [5,000 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+csv) tagged [tag:python] and [tag:csv], plus extensive documentation elsewhere, and this isn't a terribly difficult task.

Comment: Note that your current attempt puts *the string `'worddict'`*, not the dictionary you just carefully built, into `puzzle`. I suggest you read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries and https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html - `csv.DictReader` can do most of this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your input file is tab-separated, you can do this in a few lines of code:

```
import csv    

with open(filename) as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(
        file,
        delimiter='\t',
        fieldnames=['y', 'x', 'box', 'direction', 'word', 'clue'],
    )
    puzzle = {dct['word']: dct for dct in reader}
```

This gives me:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(puzzle)
{'BARD': {'box': '10',
          'clue': 'Singing poet',
          'direction': 'A',
          'word': 'BARD',
          'x': '11',
          'y': '0'},
 'CRASH': {'box': '5',
           'clue': 'Stock market calamity',
           'direction': 'A',
           'word': 'CRASH',
           'x': '5',
           'y': '0'},
 'PAID': {'box': '1',
          'clue': 'Gave money to',
          'direction': 'A',
          'word': 'PAID',
          'x': '0',
          'y': '0'}}
```

See the docs on [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), which does most of the work.